# Minimax heuristic vs. alpha-beta pruning and computation time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, search

I am working on a minimax solver for tic-tac-toe on a 5x5 board. My first attempt had to be limited to a recursive depth of 7 to limit computation time to about 20 seconds on my laptop. I then implemented alpha-beta pruning as well as a function to sort moves prior to recursively scoring them according to a heuristic (basically sorting moves earlier that brought the player close to an unblocked 5-in-a-row, or blocked rows/columns/diagonals that the opponent was close to winning). These two changes dramatically reduced processing time, and I know worked as intended because the total number of moves evaluated by the algorithm also dropped significantly, indicating that pruning was taking place.

My question concerns my next step, was to implement a heuristic board evaluator to calculate a heuristic score for a board once I've reached the set limit on recursive depth (before this I simply returned a score of 0). This heuristic was similar to the move sorter, but different because it simply scored an entire board, without considering the latest move that produced the board.

My question is, even a well-designed heuristic board evaluator would not improve processing time/reduce the number of moves to evaluate, but rather should just help the algorithm to choose a *better* move, right?

Since it is only applied at the recursive depth limit, it wouldn't have an impact on alpha-beta pruning, nor would the heuristic score affect move sorting, since the sorting occurs before the recursive calls, and the heuristic scorer is only called in one of the recursive base cases? I just want to make sure I'm understanding what effect I should hope for if I design my heuristic evaluator well.

On that note, I'm really just guessing as to how to heuristically score a 5x5 tic-tac-toe board, by giving points for the number of Maximizer's pieces in a given win condition that includes no Minimizer pieces, and subtracting points for the reverse. My code for this is below, I would also appreciate any suggestions!

```js
const heuristic = (board) => {
    let score = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        if (board[0][i]) {
            abConditions[i].forEach(array => {
                if (board[0][i] === 'o') {
                    let oScore = 0
                    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        if (board[0][array[j]] === 'o' || board[0][array[j]] === null) {
                            oScore++
                        } else {
                            oScore = 0
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    score += oScore
                } else {
                    let xScore = 0
                    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        if (board[0][array[j]] === 'x' || board[0][array[j]] === null) {
                            xScore++
                        } else {
                            xScore = 0
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    score -= xScore
                }
            })
        }
    }
    return score
}
```

Just trust me that the abConditions array is properly used to check all the win conditions on a 5x5 board :)

Comment: While I'm afraid this open-ended a question is not a good fit for StackOverflow, it is interesting.  I am confused about how you did alpha-beta without already having a heuristic evaluation.  Do you only prune for positions where there is a forced win for one side?  Developing a heuristic is of course challenging, but once you have one, you can use it as part of your pruning: if the score is above x/below y, prune the current branch; or in more sophisticated situations, spend more or less resources (e.g. clock time) evaluating a branch based on its initial heuristic score.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I suppose maybe my "heuristic" in my initial attempt at alpha-beta was weighting board scores by recursive depth? My initial base cases were only win, loss, and draw; for wins I returned 100 points minus the depth, losses -100 plus the depth, in order to more strongly prefer/avoid earlier wins/losses. I guess I hadn't even thought of that as a heuristic, but I think you mean that the alpha-beta values will not change & will not be meaningful/useful unless there is some heuristic to differentiate scores other than simply win/lose?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The algorithm used for alpha-beta pruning can be used when you don't have an exact result but only a score high/low enough to justify abandoning a branch. It can mean that you avoid a branch that has some difficult-to-find win buried in it, but that's the tradeoff you have to make when you cannot solve fully. I'm not sure any of this helps you all that much.  In theory of course, you can solve this game with a simple algorithm. In practice, there are too many paths to calculate. An alpha-beta pruning with your +-100+depth scores helps.  Other heuristics might too.